# map of vectors C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Hi if I C++ I created an STL map of the type `map<int, vec<double>>` are the vectors stored under the different keys placed consecutively in memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Technically, that would be dependent on implementation of map, but in general, a map is implemented as a Tree, so the stores are not consecutive in memory, due to the nature of the tree datastructure.

Comment: I don't think you can implement a `map` that meets the complexity constraints in the standard with anything other than a balanced binary tree.

Answer (score 8):

No.<sup>*</sup>

A map *dynamically* allocates elements as required.  So each `vector` could be placed anywhere in memory (and may move over time).

Remember also that the element storage within the `vector` itself is also dynamically allocated.  So even if you just created a straightfoward `std::vector<double> my_vectors[10]`, the elements themsleves would not be contiguous between the individual vectors.

<sub>* An implementation could conceivably allocate from an array-backed store, but you wouldn't be able to rely on this behaviour.  So it's best to assume "no".</sub>